# sending e-mail via exchange unsuccessfully

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server

I can't find anywhere where I have a problem sending emails, it only happens to some users, while for others everything normally works with this code:

```
 Dim service As New ExchangeService(requestedServerVersion:=ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1)
    Sub SendMail(ByVal Mailadressen As List(Of String), ByVal CCAdressen As List(Of String), ByVal Betreff As String, ByVal MailText As String, ByVal Anhang As List(Of String), Optional ByVal Absender As String = "")
        
        service.Url = New Uri("https://mail.server.com/ews/exchange.asmx")
      


        'Add a valid user credentials  
      
        service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("someuser", "somepasw", "somedomain")
       

        'To address the SSL challenge 
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)

        Try            'Create new message object and set properties required to send a mail 

            Dim sender As New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress
            Dim message As EmailMessage = New EmailMessage(service)
            message.Subject = Betreff
            message.Body = MailText

            If Absender <> "" Then
                Absender = Absender
                sender.Address = Absender
                message.From = sender
            End If

            For Each adr As String In Mailadressen
                message.ToRecipients.Add(adr)
            Next


            For Each cc As String In CCAdressen
                message.CcRecipients.Add(cc)
            Next

            For Each a As String In Anhang
                message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(a)
            Next

           
            message.SendAndSaveCopy()
          
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.StackTrace))
        End Try

    End Sub
```

error I'm getting:

> At Microsoft.Excange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse
> (IEwsHttpWebRequest request) at
> Microsoft.Excange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest
> (IEwsHttpWebRequest & request
> .WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems (Inumerable1
> items, FolderId parentFolderId, NUllable1 messageDisposition,
> NUllable1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling) at
> Microsoft.Excange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate1
> messageDisposition1 .WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend
> (FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDispostition)

can you please give me some suggestion what could be the problem here? thanks a lot

Comment: You've shown the part of the error stack, but not all of it. Can you include the actual error you're getting?

Comment: At a guess, if it's working for some users but not others, would suggest to me there may not be a problem with your code but either environmental issues or authentication

Comment: @AndrewMortimer an error has been inserted.